# A urn containing $n$ balls, numbered $1,2,...,n$, and $k$ balls are chosen at random without replacement.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a homework question with specific $n$ and $k$ given for the below question, but I would rather understand how this works for any given $n$ or $k$ to build my intuition for these questions.

A urn containing $n$ balls, numbered $1,2,...,n$, and $k$ balls are chosen at random without replacement. Let $X$ be the largest-numbered ball removed. Determine the probability function of $X$.

$X$ takes values from $S$

My thoughts: In the number set from $1,2,...,k-1$, all of these numbers have zero probability of being the greatest number. We then have probability of *not* drawing a specific ball(say ball $x\in S$) $\frac{n-1}{n}*\frac{n-2}{n-1},...,\frac{n-k}{n-k+1}$ = $Pr(Q)$. Then the probability thus of drawing that specific ball is merely $1 - Pr(Q)$

The probability of each number being the greatest goes up towards number $n$. So $1 - Pr(Q)$ should actually be the probability $n$ is the greatest number drawn. But that doesn't workout mentally, because it would seem the probability that ball numbered $n-1$ is the largest number drawn, would be $1 - pr(Q)$ take away the probability that ball numbered $n$ is drawn, which has the same probability, and therefore the probability of getting ball numbered $n-1$ would be zero.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest, as you pointed out, is one of $k,k+1,\dots,n$.

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely ways to choose $k$ balls.

Let us count the number of "favourables," that is, the number of ways to choose $k$ balls with $m$ the largest.

So we must choose $k-1$ balls from the balls $1,2,\dots,m-1$ to keep $m$ company. Or perhaps to be bullied by $m$.  There are $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$ ways to do this.

Now you should be able to write down an expression for $\Pr(X=m)$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. One further question:
If it was done with placement, I would merely take each case and change it to $(_{k-1}^{m+k-2})$?

Comment: In that case we can have several instances of $m$. The probability is $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k-\left(\frac{m-1}{n}\right)^k$.

Comment: I am not certain I understand why this is the case. My thoughts: We have the probability of getting a specific m or less over the k picks, take away the probability of getting less than m. Is this correct logic?

Comment: Yes, it is the probability all choices are $\le m$, minus the probability all choices are $\le m-1$. One could give an analysis along similar lines for the no replacement version, but initially (before implification using properties of the Pascal Triangle) that looks a bit more complicated than the analysis I gave.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That all makes perfect sense.

Comment: You are welcome.